# SQL Database backup

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-backups

Can I take a backup of a database in sql server developer edition?
I am running this code

`backup database Test_db to disk = d:\DailyBackUp`.

This code is running successfully but the folder `DailyBackUp` is still empty.

Comment: Is SQL Server running on your local machine?? If not: the backup will be created **on the server machine's** file system - **NOT** your local disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my solution.
Create 2 file
1/ BackupScript.sql

> DECLARE @MyBackupName nvarchar(250)
>
> SET @MyBackupName = 'C:\Projects\ABC\DB Backup\YouDBFileName_' +
>   convert( varchar(10), getdate(), 112 ) + '.BAK'
>
> BACKUP DATABASE [YouDBFileName] TO DISK = @MyBackupName    WITH
>   NOFORMAT,     NOINIT,      NAME = N'DatabaseName-Full Database
>   Backup',     SKIP,     NOREWIND,     NOUNLOAD,      STATS = 10

2/ AutoBackup.bat

> PATH = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn\"
>   SQLCMD.EXE -S . -E -i "C:\Projects\ABC\DB Backup\BackupScript.sql"

Change your parameters if need
Now you can run **AutoBackup.bat** and it auto create db backup like "YouDBFileName_20120325.bak"

Comment: You can create a schedule (Start menu->Accessories->System tool->Task Schedule) to do daily backup.

Answer (score 2):

you have to specify the name of the backup

```
backup database Test_db to disk = d:\DailyBackUp\BackupFileName.Bak
```

Comment: Msg 3201, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot open backup device 'd:\DailyBackUp\BackupFileName.Bak'. Operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: it is looks like a security issue: make sure on that folder the account "Network Service" has got "Write" permission
if you still have the error probably SQL is not able to write on your partition.To test is this is the issue try to backup on C: instead

Comment: @Peluso I have tried in c drive then also giving the same errors.Please help

Comment: make also sure the folder d:\DailyBackUp\ exist on your SQL Server machine

Comment: @Peluso How to check the Network Serveice.Please explain briefly

Comment: right click on d:\DailyBackUp folder -->property-->security
cick on edit and give full control to the user "Network Service"

This may help too :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557490/why-cant-i-backup-database-using-t-sql